# Optimize the slow query in-memory List using LINQ for retrieving data

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a LINQ query that I am having trouble optimizing. It takes about 6 seconds to run.

```
IList<Note> notes;
data = client.Configuration.Data.OfType<UWData>()
    .Where(s => s.ShouldDisplay)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Id)
    .ToList()
    .Select(n => (Note)n)
    .ToList();
```

`client.Configuration.Data` contains hundreds of thousands of data (100,000 items).
`client.Configuration.Data` is a cache, and I am retrieving data from the cache.
`client.Configuration.Data` contains 100,000 items, and we have 10 items which is the type of `UWData`. I want to select the 10 `UWData`.

```
var data = client.Configuration.Data.OfType<UWData>().ToList();
data = UWData
    .Where(s => s.ShouldDisplay)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Id)
    .ToList()
    .Select(n => (Note)n)
    .ToList();
```

The above code also taking a similar time to load.
Sometimes it takes around 4 seconds to load (exactly 3,356 ms).
Any ideas on how I could speed this up?

Comment: Performance depends on type of database being used and size.  You may not be able to speed up results.  The driver used to connect to database can also effect speed.  What database are you using and which driver?  See following for list of drivers : https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: @jdweng client.Configuration.Data is a cache
it consists of different types of Data - eg: UWData, VFData,..
I am retrieving data from the cache.

Comment: If you are retrieving data from a cache, then why `entity-framework` tag? Remove the tag and specify in the question that you are running LINQ in-memory query (LINQ to Objects).

Comment: How many items does the list contains? how many items are `UWData`? Is the `Configuration.Data` a regular list or something generated on demand? Have you done any profiling?

Comment: You have to identify (profile) which part of the query is slowing it down. Start by removing `.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).ToList()` and let us know what is the time compared to the original 6 seconds.

Comment: Please remember that most of us who don't live in India have no idea what is "lakhs of data", at best they can guess it's "lack of data". So please don't use Indian words here.

Comment: Questions about improving performance can't be answered without sufficient details of *all* involved parts. Which generally means: can't be answered. See also: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: @JonasH items in the list -> 100000, items in UWData -> 10.
client.Configuration.Data contains 100000 items, and we have 10 items which is the type of UWData. I want to select the 10 UWData.

Comment: If there are 10^5 items in memory, your problem is probably not the posted query. linear, or even `n log n` complexity, for that many items should be in the order of tens to a hundreds of milliseconds, not seconds. **Use a profiler!**

Comment: @IvanStoev it takes the same time even if we remove the item '.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).ToList()'

Comment: Check you memory usage in task manager.  When you run out of memory you will use swap space which is on your hard drive and then performance will be extremely slow.

Comment: Then there is nothing that can be optimized in the shown code. The culprit apparently is in the `Data` cache implementation. You use terms like "cache", "loading" which are totally unclear (people are assuming cache to be some sort of list, but then there wouldn't be such thing as loading), so you really need to find out what is causing the performance issue and how/if it can be improved.  All that inside "cache" implementation, there is nothing we can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are using some sort of ORM remember to keep an eye out for SQL joins (you could extract the generated SQL of your ORM) also as best practice select only necessary columns and use indexes